# Telerik error: Could not load type 'Telerik.WebControls.Dialogs.SpellCheckControl'

Tags: telerik, spell-checking

I am getting following error while trying to build my ASP.NET websie.

```
Error 1 Could not load type 'Telerik.WebControls.Dialogs.SpellCheckControl'.    
D:\MyApp\RadControls\Spell\Dialogs\Controls\SpellCheck.ascx
```

This was working fine earlier, but recently all developers are facing this issue, and unable to build application.

what could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share some of the source of your SpellCheck user control?

Are you getting this error server-side?

It sounds like the registration of the AJAX controls in your project has gotten hosed, you could try re-registering the controls with the project from within Visual Studio by running a Telerik - "RadControls for ASP.Net AJAX" - Configure Project